# angularjs sublime text $scope not recognized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am starting with Angular and installed all Angular packages for Sublime Text 3.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
      <p>{{author.title + ', ' + author.sex}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myController($scope){
      $scope.author = {
        'name' : 'Ivan',
        'ocupation' : 'student',
        'subject' : 'cs'
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is not working I get plain text when I open the page.
Its not recognising anything I write after "$" in the function body, I can see that because it is colouring only the $ and it doesn't connect the $scope in the () brackets and the one inside the function body.
Any ideas? Been trying to fix that for a day now.

Comment: Actually it wasnt working because I missed closing curly brackets for the function. Also this will not work with Angular 1.3.0, it works with 1.2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6HLIDHa2XGZMNRrDT583?p=preview)

You should define angular module and controller.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
      <p>{{author.ocupation}}, {{author.subject}}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.author = {
        'name' : 'Ivan',
        'ocupation' : 'student',
        'subject' : 'cs'
      }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That did work.
How come I need to define module and controller and in none of the tutorials anyone is?